# Enable gzip compression on NGINX Unit

Tags: nginx, nginx-unit

Enabling gzip compression on pure NGINX [is relatively simple](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/). However, I want to enable gzip compression for **NGINX Unit**. I'm not seeing anything on the [NGINX Unit configuration man page](https://unit.nginx.org/configuration/#static-files) about how to do the same for NGINX Unit. Is the option not currently supported? Is it just not documented on that page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP then you can enable it using [zlib](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php). Otherwise, it's not supported yet.

P.S. Feel free to leave feature request on [Unit GitHub page](https://github.com/nginx/unit/issues) if you are looking for this functionality.